# Take a lat/long pair from JavaScript for use in date_sunset in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, date

I have decided i'd like to do an ambitious mood change depending on the time of day. I need to get the time and compare it against the sunset and sunrise of any given day.

So far I have found some javascript [here](http://www.maxmind.com/app/javascript_city) that works well. Can anyone tell me how I might give the lat and long to the PHP function date_sunset? I have the IP in a PHP variable using        `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` but that's all I have. I can't really do much else as I have never used the function and never tried to combine PHP and JS. Any ideas?

-- Update --

I have been trying to use the jQuery $.ajax function. Here is my code;

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var lat = geoip_latitude();
var long = geoip_longitude();
$(document).ready(function(){
   //var url = 'http://www.ransomedesign.co.uk/web/?lat=' + lat + '&long='+ long;
   // $.get(url);
  $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  data: { lat:lat, long:long},
  url: "http:www.ransomedesign.co.uk/web/",
  success: function() { alert("you win"); }
  })
});
</script>
```

There are two different approaches in there. (1st one is commented out). This does populate my $_SERVER php code, but only on the 2nd request of a page for my site. I really need this to process on the first visit before anything loads. After this the value will be stored in a session and php will do the rest.

Can anyone see whats wrong with this code or why it wont work straight away? My php if after this, is that correct?

Many thanks...

Comment: Really you will only need to worry about the latitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question had no answer as such, I ended up getting a PHP module and .dat file installed on my hosting for me. The AJAX did work, but only after a page from my site had been visited - which was no use sadly. Thanks for the help everyone..

Answer (score 0):

Given that snippet there, you'd have two variables, `geoip_latitude`, and `geoip_longitude`. Take those variables, put them into an AJAX call to your server, which would then do the calculations:

html:

```
<div id="sunset"></div>

<script>
    $('#sunset').load('/path/to/script.php?lat=' + geoip_latitude + '&lon=' & geoip_longitude);
</script>
```

php:

```
<?php

$lat = $_GET['lat'];
$lon = $_GET['lon'];

echo date_sunset(time(), SUNFUNCS_RET_STRING, $lat, $long);
```

This assumes you've got jquery loaded/available and the server's on PHP v5. I'm also using the server's time, which could be on a different day than the client entirely. Probably won't work out of the box, but should get you started.

Comment: thanks very much for the reply. I will look at this and try to work out what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use AJAX for this. You use GeoIP JavaScript, so first get `lat` and `long`:

```
var lat = geoip_latitude () ;
var long = geoip_longitude () ;
```

then send it to server script, for example `mood.php`:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest () ;
xhr . onreadystatechange = function ()
{
   if ( xhr . readyState == 4 && xhr . status == 200 )
   {
      // do something with server response
   }
}
xhr . open ( "POST", "mood.php", true ) ;
xhr . setRequestHeader ( "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" ) ;
xhr . send ( "lat=" + lat + "&long=" + long ) ;
```

and mood.php might looks like:

```
<?php
   $lat = $_POST [ "lat" ] ;
   $long = $_POST [ "long" ] ;

   echo "something depending on lat and long" ;
?>
```

edit.

If server sends response, you can read it by calling `xhr . responseText`:

```
xhr . onreadystatechange = function ()
{
   if ( xhr . readyState == 4 && xhr . status == 200 )
   {
      alert ( "Server response: " + xhr . responseText ) ;
   }
}
```

If server sends XML content, then you can call `xhr . responseXML` - it tiggers native XML parser.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX/Getting_Started

Comment: Thanks this this, Im going to look at both replies and try to work out what to do. I have never used AJAX, although jQuery is already up and running for other stuff on my website.

Comment: Hi, i'm just trying to get this working - in the commented bit that says do something with server response, what should I put? So far I have set this up to send the variables to header.php in my WordPress theme, it's not returning anything...

Comment: Hi, Im trying to do this a slightly different way now, im trying to get the values into a PHP SESSION using a get. The lat and long are being added to the URL by AJAX. I'm still having some issues though, I have updated my original post if you fancy taking a look...